# while loop in Number prototype extension calls function once, then errors undefined

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I'm trying to extend the JS Number prototype to include a Ruby-esque ".times" method (the merits of this pursuit are an issue for another time).

Here is my code:

```
Number.prototype.times = function(doThis) {
  val = +this;
  while (val > 0 ) {
    doThis();
    val--;
  }
}
```

If I try

`5..times(console.log(1));`

I get the following output:

```
foo
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'doThis()')
```

Why does the loop work on the first iteration and fail on the second?

(note: the goal is to make the Number prototype extension such that calling it is highly expressive, intuitive, and reads more like natural language, like Ruby's [.times](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Integer.html#method-i-times) method.)

Comment: The '..' after the '5' is necessary because the interpreter reads the first dot as part of the numeric literal.

Answer (score 4):

Your `Number.prototype.times` function is written to **take another function as argument** (which you're then calling with `doThis()`).

However, when calling the `times` function, you're not passing another function as a parameter, but then return value of `console.log(1)` which will most likely be `undefined` (which you're then trying to call as a function, resulting in the *undefined is not a function* error).

Instead, pass a function that's calling `console.log(1)`:

```
5..times(function() {
    console.log(1);
});
```

Comment: My goal is write the .times() function in a way that makes calling it very terse.  Is there a way to change .times() rather than the argument it takes?

Comment: @meetalexjohnson `console.log(1)` returns undefined, which is then passed to the method without any information where the value came from. That's a fundamental feature of the language and you can't change that.

Comment: @helmbert I want a really terse way to write a loop when I know exactly how many times I want the loop to run.  So, if I wanted 5 "foo"s logged, I could use '5..times(console.log("foo"))"

Comment: @meetalexjohnson: `(5).times(console.log.bind(console,1))`

Answer (score 0):

Your function reminds me of libraries like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/), which provide a lot of functions that let you make very succinct code.

Here is how I might implement this with lodash, which provides a [_.times()](https://lodash.com/docs#times) utility function:

```
Number.prototype.times = function(cb) {
  return _.times(+this, cb);
}
```

You could use the [_.partial()](https://lodash.com/docs#partial) to make it more readable than an explicit `function() {}` wrapper:

```
5..times(_.partial(console.log,"blah"));
```

Or, if you wanted to put the partial into your `times` function it could be a little more readable:

```
Number.prototype.times = function () {
    return _.times(+this, _.partial.apply(this,arguments));
};

5..times(console.log,"blah");

// can still be used with an arbitrary function block:
5..times(function() { console.log("some other block"); });
```

---

Here is [a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dsummersl/m8bav0q5/7/).

Answer (score -1):

change to this:

```
Number.prototype.times = function(doThis) {
  val = +this;
  while (val > 0 ) {
    doThis();
    val--;
  }
}
5..times(function () {console.log(1)});
```